# There is something wrong with the if-statement in our setter

Tags: java, if-statement, setter, bluej

We are making a setter with the if-statement. We are trying to limit the approved values, and are using a print-method to print out the value that is set, or "wrong" if the value is not accepted.

This is the method:

```
Public class Sykkel extends Kjøretøy
{

private int height;


public Sykkel(String colour)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    super(1, colour);
    this.height = height;
}

public void setHeight (int height) {
    if(height > 35 && height < 70){
        System.out.println("Sykkelen er " + height + " cm høy.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
```

No matter what we set as the height it prints out "Wrong". Does anyone see the error in the code?

we've tried both this.height and just height, but the outcome is still the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like the line `this.height = height;` in your constructor doesn't make much sense - what would `height` be in that context? There is no such parameter handed in. Apart from that, maybe show us how you actually call `setHeight()`?

Comment: **1.** What value is on the right side of the assignment `this.height = height;`? **2.** What value is tested in `if(height > 35 && height < 70)` – is it the function's parameter `height` or the member `this.height`? In the latter case the result strongly depends on an answer to the first question.

Comment: You would have to provide the original code, this one has obvious compilation errors, so it is hard to deduce what could be wrong. Other thing is, is it single threaded code or you use some multithreading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My observations.

Your constructor should be:

```
public Sykkel(String colour, int height)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    super(1, colour);
    this.height = height;
}
```

---

In your `setHeight` method, you need to assign the height to the instance variable.

```
public void setHeight (int height) {
    if(height > 35 && height < 70){
        System.out.println("Sykkelen er " + height + " cm høy.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
    // add the below line:
    this.height = height;
}
```

---

The other method seems okay.

When I call `setHeight(40);`, I am getting

```
Sykkelen er 40 cm høy.
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no assignment in setter method, just append

> this.height = height;

```
public void setHeight (int height) {
    if(height > 35 && height < 70){
        System.out.println("Sykkelen er " + height + " cm høy.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
 this.height = height; 
}
```